# Why pygame doesn't work inside functions?

Tags: python, pygame, wav

I have added a wav file to play on certain instances, but it doesn't work when I put the code in a function and invoke somewhere else. Also when I change indentation.  I tried mp3 but the same problem occurred.

This code works properly:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("../audio/Humi.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
    continue
```

This code doesn't work:

```
def func():
   pygame.mixer.init()
   pygame.mixer.music.load("../audio/Humi.wav")
   pygame.mixer.music.play()
   while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
      continue
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
File "D:\GitANN.py", line 34, in Predicions
  pygame.mixer.music.load("../audio/Humi.wav")
pygame.error: Couldn't open '../audi/Humi.wav'
```

Comment: When asking a question like this, you should _really_ provide a stack trace when you say "it doesn't work".

Comment: Well... at least your current code is having wrong indention....

Comment: Do you ever call `func`?

Comment: Yes I call it. Also tried without it

Comment: you changed the current working directory before calling func.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Before the `pygame.mixer.music.load()` calls. add a `print(os.getcwd())` and see if the current working directory is the same in both cases. If not, you will need to save and restore it (with `os.chdir`) or specify an absolute path to the .wav file.

Comment: You should be able create an absolute path to the data file by using `curdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)` and then `wavpath = os.path.join(curdir, 'audi/Humi.wav')`.

Comment: @martineau, I wish to do this with relative path. That's why I'm in this problem. Absolute path is not the solution

Comment: @martineau Tried to give absolute path. But got the same problem. Can you give me a complete example if you don't mind?

Comment: try using `from pygame import mixer` and replace everything in the func() from `pygame.mixer.` to just `mixer.` for example `mixer.init()` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, what I was suggesting that you do in my comment to get an absolute path to the audio file wouldn't work. I missed the fact that you had a two dot `..` prefix on the relative path to the .wav file.

The core of the idea—get and use an absolute path to the audio file—is still viable, however. It just needs to be done a little differently (and it's actually somewhat easier).

This worked when I tested it (whether the path to the wave file was used by a `pygame.mixer.music.load()` call inside a function or not).

Note: Instead of referencing a global variable in the function as shown, it would be better to add a path parameter to the function and pass the string to it as an argument. It would probably also be better to call `pygame.mixer.init()` only once, outside the function, rather than every time it's called.

```
import os
import pygame

def func():
   pygame.mixer.init()
   pygame.mixer.music.load(wavpath)  # Uses global variable.
   pygame.mixer.music.play()
   while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
      pass

wavpath = os.path.abspath('../audio/Humi.wav')
func()
```